# Issues with session in Codeigniter3 framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

My website works properly in localhost, however, it sometimes give this error when I open it in live https://wtf.az/test . Where can be the problem?

[image: error]

Comment: you do not have permissions to remove the file. Usually ownership mismatch between user uploading the files and user used to serve it.

Comment: Is your htaccess file is right? can you check with this link https://wtf.az/test/index.php

Comment: @AnandPandey it shows it sometimes, not always

Comment: Ok plz follow the answer step, it will not show anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too so do the following. In the config.php file you MUST set sess_save_path to a valid path. It was initially set to NULL.

Now the sessions are being saved in this folder and can be unlinked when needed to

change application > config > config.php

```
$config['sess_save_path'] =  BASEPATH . 'cache/';
```

Please give the permission to 777 on cache folder, so when cache write on that folder it will accessible.

Comment: Cache folder permission

Comment: Does it located in application > config > config.php ?

Comment: No its in the folder=> system/cache

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the session settings in config.php.

Kindly comment out below lines:
//$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
//$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
And add a new line.
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/';